# Doubt about exact sequence.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Maybe this is an elementary question however I don't know much algebra. Is it true that if $$0\longrightarrow A\longrightarrow B\longrightarrow C\longrightarrow D\longrightarrow 0$$ is an exact sequence of abelian groups then $A\longrightarrow B$ is an isomorphism?

Answer (score 4):

No. For example, the sequence
$$
0\to \Bbb Z\xrightarrow{2}\Bbb Z\to\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z\to 0\to 0
$$
is exact but the map $\Bbb Z\xrightarrow{2}\Bbb Z$ is not an isomorphism.

If, however, the map $B\to C$ is $0$, then we know that $A\to B$ is an isomorphism (can you see why?).

Comment: Nice! Yes I can. Thanks..

Comment: This response should be selected as the official answer.